# How read data coming from forkjoin map?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm new to angular and rxjs and I need to know how can I read data which are coming from forkJoin on a map.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.serviceData.currentService.subscribe(service =>
        this.serviceFam.getAllFamilles().pipe(
          switchMap(familles =>
            forkJoin(
              familles.map(f => forkJoin(
                this.serviceAffecter.getAffecterServiceFamille(service, f.nom),
                this.serviceOpe.getOperationsServiceFamille(service, f.nom)
                ).pipe(
                map(([listAffecter, listeOperations]) => [f, listAffecter, listeOperations])
                )
              )
            )
          )
        ).pipe(switchMap((data: [Famille, Affecter, Operation][]) => {
          return forkJoin(data.map((f, a, o) => {

            //Here I want to read my data

          }));
        }))
    );

    this.serviceData.changeAffaire(4);
  }
```

Comment: Just tap after switchMap `pipe(switchMap(), tap(console.log))`

Answer (score 0):

This is rather messy to read, but, within the code of code for `switchMap`, but you can use the [tap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) operator to log the responses.

```
forkJoin(
  familles.map(f => forkJoin(
    this.serviceAffecter.getAffecterServiceFamille(service, f.nom),
    this.serviceOpe.getOperationsServiceFamille(service, f.nom)
  ).pipe(
    tap(res => {
      console.log(res);
    }),
    map(([listAffecter, listeOperations]) => [f, listAffecter, listeOperations])
  ))
)
```